# Make EditText accept and display HTML formatted text

Tags: android, android-edittext

Does any one know how to make an `EditText` control shows html formatted text, and even writes HTML formatted text, to act like an HTML Edit Box,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To show HTML code in an `EditText` you need to convert it to `Spanned` using `Html.fromHtml()`. Only a small HTML tag subset can be used in this method. You can set a `Spanned` as a text of an `EditText`. Then you can edit it and convert it back using `Html.toHtml()`.

Comment: While setting Text to my EditText the formatting of my text gets removed.

Comment: Maybe I will be able to help you if you show how you do it. Formatting can disappear if you call `toString()` for the result of `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: More HTML tags support and compatibility library for Android's Html class: HtmlCompat, https://github.com/Pixplicity/HtmlCompat

Answer (score 16):

Try using [`Html.fromHtml(text)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) to display HTML formatted text in `EditText`.

But `Html` class can recognize only few tags, its not comprehensive. You can check [this blog](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) to check which all tags are supported as of now.

Answer (score 1):

```
String xyz="this <br>is<br> my<br> testing <br>string ";
 String formattedString =Html.fromHtml(xyz);
```