# Text viewed as HTML

Tags: android

Hey everyone this is a update from my previous question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676440/android-showing-a-edittext-text-in-webview

I got the webview to see the text inside my Edit text field but its displaying it as text
this is the coding im using

```
    case R.id.Preview:
        Intent j = new Intent(this, Preview.class);
        j.putExtra(com.afajje.htmlzero.Preview.URL, 
                myEditText.getText().toString());
        startActivity(j);
}
return false;}
```

Want im trying to have it do is view the Edit text, text as HTML

For example if I put in the Edittext field

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a Preview</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In the web view itll just just the "This is a Preview"

Comment: This previous question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288898/make-edittext-accept-and-display-html-formatted-text-android

Comment: Thank you for the link :) do you know somewhere, where I can view some code? Im a newbie :/

Comment: I have posted an answer below with an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go, a working demo:

```
package com.stackexchange.test;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.text.Html; 
import android.text.Spanned; 
import android.widget.EditText;

public class home extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        EditText box = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        String htmltext = "<b>This is bold. </ b> and <i> this is italic </ i>." ; 
        Spanned text = Html.fromHtml( htmltext ); 
        box.setText( text );
    } 
}
```

You should see (except that I've edited the text in the app):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to show the html text into the EditText.

```
 String str = "<html><head></head><body><p>This is a Preview</p></body></html>";
 editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
 editText.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

[image]

Comment: It works :) but its not what im trying to do :/
so far I have a preview menu button, when its clicked it goes into a webview viewing a URL

IM trying to get it so that the webview reads whats in the EditText Field such as a HTML setup and display it in the webview

Comment: so you want the html text which is set to editText . am i right ?

Comment: yes if the html text is inside the editText then the webview well read it displaying "This is a preview"

Comment: These pics might help :P

http://i51.tinypic.com/169qgld.png
http://i56.tinypic.com/2ppecmt.png

Comment: Well I want kinda want it to do same thing in your answer, but instend of the html showing in a editText field, show in a webView

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the editText, if you dont use "Html.fromHtml", the string will be display with the html tags. In a WebView, I really dont know what zou want to do...sorry

Comment: I understand that bud I don't know what the code looks like :/

Comment: An example using an editText could be:
`String str = "<br>This is a Preview</br>";
 editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
 editText.setText(str);`
So, in this case, inside the EditText you will have "<br>This is a Preview</br>" with all the html tags.