# How to implement a complete HTML page on Android without using WebView

Tags: android

I have a string which consumes the html code of a form and I want to show that form in my app and it should also work further as on submit it should move forward to next page.

I used WebView, it just shows the page in a static way. It don't support buttons and DatePicker, so I DONT WANT WEBVIEW.

Comment: You can open HTML in edittext.
See the link below,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288898/make-edittext-accept-and-display-html-formatted-text-android

Comment: I know what is in it, Its a complete form using form attributes, table layout, textfields, buttons etc.

Comment: Actually it is a complete online application form having all form attributes like::- table layout, textfields, buttons etc.
What I really need is to show that form as an Activity in my app, and when user click on SUBMIT button (which is in form), It works forward as it is doing on browser.
I tried to use TextView to show it as a page, but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, WebView does support buttons, and you could support a DatePicker either by using [an HTML/JS one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) or by doing something fancy to route a request to the Java side of things. I really suspect your insistence on not using WebView is going to prove unproductive.

That said, sure you should show your HTML in your app without using WebView... you could write your own web control or take another (Firefox is open source as is WebKit on which WebView is based, in fact so is WebView itself for that matter). That's going to be a heck of a lot of work though.

Comment: This is the exact DatePicker which is used at that site and its also coming in with that html code which i have kept to display. This datePicker is not working in WEBVIEW.

Comment: I just tried on an Android device and the date picker demo at that URL works for me. It does pop up the soft keyboard though so you'd have to do something to suppress that.