# How can I make any selected text in an EditText Bold or Italic in android studio and store it into a SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, html, xml

How can I make any **selected** text in an EditText **Bold** or *Italic* in android studio and **store it** into a SQLite database?

Comment: You can use and store HTML. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288898/make-edittext-accept-and-display-html-formatted-text) in StackOverflow.

Comment: You cant store bold text in the sqlite database , But whenever you get a string from db,you can convert it into your desired style.

Comment: Yes, but i have to retrieve the same formatted text whenever user wants to see it , i'm making a simple "Notes" app so i need the same text formatted by the user when he/she created the note. any way i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

> First make a class to get the start and end position of the selected text.
> And a style variable for storing bold, italic or underline

```
class typefaces{
```

int style,start,end;
}

> Then store the variable of the edittext in the database

```
start = edittext.selectionstart();
end = edittext.selectionend();
dbhelper.insertTypes(style,start,end);
```

> add the values to the database and retrieve to again show the saved.
> Use spans to add bold, italics and underline types